# Capacitor not fully charging

Tags: capacitor-charging

There is a problem with this circuit. The original document specified 3V for power supply. However, the capacitor 13 is only charges to around 0.8v and then stops when I used 3V and it doesn't trigger SCR 7. I tried 9v and it works sometimes with this voltage. When I disconnect the gate of SCR 7, it seems to be charging fully. I am using TICP106D SCR. In the original document the SCR was BRY55. Both are sensitive gate SCR as far as know, so they should (?) be interchangeable. I don't understand why the current is leaking this much through the gate. Do you have any suggestion?
[image]

Comment: get a sensitive gate SCR. The  5 to 200uA is too high. try 1uA

Comment: It might be interesting to know what the purpose of the circuit is - that would make understanding what might be wrong with it easier

Comment: Do sensitive SCR have lower leak through gate?

Comment: It's a break wire alarm.@ Marcus

Comment: P010xx has 1uA Igt max  or P0130AA or make your own with two 2n5088

Comment: This is an old patent for a Gate turn off SCR or fuse wire latch or whatever application.

Comment: Yes Tony I want to use it for tent protection when I go camping.

Comment: Hmm how about a dog.

Comment: Yeah but it's a week long. So basically I should be looking for low Igt?